# RMS opened for full cycle

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

Midlet starting open one RMS and store some data in it and through out each page I am using RMS for getting data.

Now I am using same open RMS for each page. Is this is efficient or I need to close and open when it use?

Comment: what does it mean "for each page"? There are no "pages" in midlet. Can you post a code snippet to show hiow you use RMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by page. If your RMS is available for several midlets and page = once midlet, then you should close store with destroying app. I think you think about page as screen. Then you must open RMS with first screen and close it with last.

Comment: page mean it as a screen in midlet.